# Question about regular surface patches

Tags: differential-geometry, chain-rule

[image]

I’m studying Differential Geometry from Pressley’s book. Two questions:

1.- Shouldn’t the $U$ in the last sentence be $\Bbb{R^3}$?

2.- How does one obtain equation 1? Why is there a cross product on the right-hand side of equation $(1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just write it out, but using some less cumbersome notation.

Let $\vec V = a\vec v + b\vec w$ and $\vec W = c\vec v + d\vec w$, where $a,b,c,d$ are scalars. Then
\begin{align*}
\vec V\times\vec W &= (a\vec v + b\vec w)\times (c\vec v + d\vec w)\\
&=ac(\vec v\times \vec v) + ad(\vec v\times\vec w) + bc(\vec w\times\vec v) + bd(\vec w\times \vec w) \\
&= (ad-bc)(\vec v\times \vec w).
\end{align*}
We used only the basic algebraic properties of the cross product.

Answer (score 0):

On your first question, you are right, instead of $U$ it should say $\Bbb{R^3}$.

On the second question, it is a common manipulation of differential forms. As you probably know, $\sigma_u \times \sigma_u=0$ and  $\sigma_v \times \sigma_v=0$, you can use the traditional definition for the cross product in $\Bbb{R^3}$ of the determinant. Using this definition as well, you can see that $\sigma_u \times \sigma_v=-\sigma_v \times \sigma_u$. Now you only have to use these two facts and operate the left hand side in $(1)$.

Comment: Wouldn’t that be a determinant in R^2? What happens when a vector is inside the determinant of the cross product formula? I guess I’m making a mistake somewhere. I’m unable to see how this cross product will actually look like inside a determinant.

Comment: It looks like Pressley's notation is the normal one when dealing with surface geometry. $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_v$ are both vectors in $\Bbb{R^3}$, so it is just the common cross product.

Comment: With the common cross product I mean the traditional way of calculating $\sigma_u \times \sigma_v$ as $det((i,j,k), \sigma_u, \sigma_v)$.

Comment: I’m still not getting it. Guess I’m not getting the notations right. What confuses me is that the equations before Eq(1) is expressed as sum. How to put that inside the determinant and arrive at Eq(1).

Comment: I see now what is the problem. The property that probably you had not heard of is the multilinearity and sum-distributivity of the cross product. See the beginning of the Wikipedia article [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)

Comment: Thank you. I checked but still unable to convince myself. I’m getting something wrong. Wish I could see this theorem explicitly proved or explained in some textbook. But unable to find one. The same thing is in Struik’s book.